# Debug the difference between two Frft implementations

Tags: fft, matlab, fourier-transform, python

I need help to understand the difference between two fractional Fourier transform implementations.

[On this website](https://nalag.cs.kuleuven.be/research/software/FRFT/) two different implementations for the fractional Fourier transform are presented (**frft**, and **frft2**). The [two](https://nalag.cs.kuleuven.be/research/software/FRFT/frft.m) [implementations](https://nalag.cs.kuleuven.be/research/software/FRFT/frft2.m) are provided as Matlab code.

The accompanying paper on the linked website describes the second implementation as using less resources **but delivering an identical result**.

I want to visualize the Fractional Fourier transform inside a web page. Of course I would prefer to use the more performant implementation. This is why I tried to translate the second implementation (**frft2**) into JavaScript.

While doing so I noticed that the resulting signal is almost but not exactly what I expected. For example I expected an even rect signal to stay approximately even when being frft-transformed (as [described on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Fourier_transform#/media/File:FracFT_Rec_by_stevencys.jpg)).

To double check I also translated the first (**frft**) implementation and noticed that now the results are as expected. So either the two implementations differ in their output, or I made a mistake translating the one implementation but not the other.

To double check again and also to stay closer to the syntax and semantics of the Matlab code, I also translated both implementations into Python using NumPy. Unfortunately this resulted in the same difference: **frft** working as expected and **frft2** being slightly off (even more off for time shifted signals).

Below you can see a plot comparing real part of `frft(rect(t), a=0.49)` (green) and `frft2(rect(t), a=0.49)` (red):

[image: Plot of frft and frft2]

In this plot the difference is not that big, but depending on the time shift of the rect and on the fractional parameter `a`, both implementations differ quite a lot.

[This is a Jupyter notebook](https://github.com/laszlokorte/frft_python_debug/blob/main/frft.ipynb) containing both my Python implementations.

This is my Python implementation of **frft** working correctly (I think):

```py
# Matlab to Python translation from
# https://nalag.cs.kuleuven.be/research/software/FRFT/frft.m

import numpy as np
import scipy
import scipy.signal

def frft(f, a):
    ret = np.zeros_like(f, dtype=np.complex128)
    f = f.copy().astype(np.complex128)
    N = len(f)
    shft = np.fmod(np.arange(N) + np.fix(N / 2), N).astype(int)
    sN = np.sqrt(N)
    a = np.remainder(a, 4.0)

    if a == 0.0:
        return f
    if a == 2.0:
        return np.flipud(f)
    if a == 1.0:
        ret[shft] = np.fft.fft(f[shft]) / sN
        return ret
    if a == 3.0:
        ret[shft] = np.fft.ifft(f[shft]) * sN
        return ret

    # reduce to interval 0.5 < a < 1.5
    if a > 2.0:
        a = a - 2.0
        f = np.flipud(f)
    if a > 1.5:
        a = a - 1
        f[shft] = np.fft.fft(f[shft]) / sN
    if a < 0.5:
        a = a + 1
        f[shft] = np.fft.ifft(f[shft]) * sN

    # the general case for 0.5 < a < 1.5
    alpha = a * np.pi / 2
    tana2 = np.tan(alpha / 2)
    sina = np.sin(alpha)
    f = np.hstack((np.zeros(N - 1), sincinterp(f), np.zeros(N - 1))).T

    # chirp premultiplication
    chrp = np.exp(-1j * np.pi / N * tana2 / 4 * np.arange(-2 * N + 2, 2 * N - 1).T ** 2)
    f = chrp * f

    # chirp convolution
    c = np.pi / N / sina / 4
    ret = scipy.signal.fftconvolve(
        np.exp(1j * c * np.arange(-(4 * N - 4), 4 * N - 3).T ** 2), f
    )
    ret = ret[4 * N - 4 : 8 * N - 7] * np.sqrt(c / np.pi)

    # chirp post multiplication
    ret = chrp * ret

    # normalizing constant
    ret = np.exp(-1j * (1 - a) * np.pi / 4) * ret[N - 1 : -N + 1 : 2]

    return ret


def ifrft(f, a):
    return frft(f, -a)


def sincinterp(x):
    N = len(x)
    y = np.zeros(2 * N - 1, dtype=x.dtype)
    y[: 2 * N : 2] = x
    xint = scipy.signal.fftconvolve(
        y[: 2 * N],
        np.sinc(np.arange(-(2 * N - 3), (2 * N - 2)).T / 2),
    )

    return xint[2 * N - 3 : -2 * N + 3]
```

This is my Python implementation of **frft2** being slightly off:

```py
# Matlab to Python translation from
# https://nalag.cs.kuleuven.be/research/software/FRFT/frft2.m

import numpy as np
import scipy
import scipy.signal

def frft2(f, a):
    f0 = f.flatten()
    N = len(f)
    sN = np.sqrt(N)
    a = np.mod(a, 4)

    if a == 0:
        return f0
    elif a == 2:
        return np.flipud(f0)
    elif a == 1:
        return np.fft.ifftshift(np.fft.fft(np.fft.fftshift(f0))) / sN
    elif a == 3:
        return np.fft.ifftshift(np.fft.ifft(np.fft.fftshift(f0))) * sN

    if a > 2.0:
        a = a - 2
        f0 = np.flipud(f0)
    if a > 1.5:
        a = a - 1
        f0 = np.fft.ifftshift(np.fft.fft(np.fft.fftshift(f0))) / sN
    if a < 0.5:
        a = a + 1
        f0 = np.fft.ifftshift(np.fft.ifft(np.fft.fftshift(f0))) * sN

    alpha = a * np.pi / 2
    s = np.pi / (N + 1) / np.sin(alpha) / 4
    t = np.pi / (N + 1) * np.tan(alpha / 2) / 4
    Cs = np.sqrt(s / np.pi) * np.exp(-1j * (1 - a) * np.pi / 4)

    f1 = fconv(f0, np.sinc(np.arange(-(2 * N - 3), 2 * N - 1, 2) / 2), 1)
    f1 = f1[N : 2 * N]
    chrp = np.exp(-1j * t * np.arange(-N, N) ** 2)
    l0 = chrp[::2]
    l1 = chrp[1::2]
    f0 = f0 * l0
    f1 = f1 * l1
    chrp = np.exp(1j * s * np.arange(-(2 * N), 2 * N - 1) ** 2)
    e1 = chrp[::2]
    e0 = chrp[1::2]
    f0 = fconv(f0, e0, 0)
    f1 = fconv(f1, e1, 0)
    h0 = np.fft.ifft(f0 + f1)

    Faf = Cs * l0 * h0[N : 2 * N]

    return Faf


def fconv(x, y, c):
    N = len(np.concatenate((x.flatten(), y.flatten()))) - 1
    P = 2 ** np.ceil(np.log2(N)).astype(int)
    z = np.fft.fft(x, P) * np.fft.fft(y, P)

    if c != 0:
        z = np.fft.ifft(z)
        z = z[N::-1]

    return z
```

Since I have not much experience in Matlab I suspect that I mistranslated some of the range syntax and included some off-by-1 errors. I already spent some hours debugging.

Both implementations map the parameter `a` into the range `(0.5, 1.5)` to make use of symmetries but for the **frft2** implementation I noticed a discontinuity at `a=0.5` and at `a=2.5`. To me it looks like this case might be handle incorrectly:

```py
if a < 0.5:
    a = a + 1
    f0 = np.fft.ifftshift(np.fft.ifft(np.fft.fftshift(f0))) * sN
```

For example with **frft** an even real signal is even for both `a=0.45` and `a=0.55`. But with **frft2** an even real signal is complex and odd for `0<a<=0.5` but suddenly even for `a>0.5`.

But I could not find the true reason for this and since both implementations map `a` into this range the actual difference might be somethere else.

I would be glad if someone could either point out my mistake or confirm that the two algorithms actually differ in their results.

---

**Update:** Now I also tried to run the Matlab code (in Octave). It looks like even the original Matlab code leads to different results. But I still do not understand why. Numerical instability? Is one of the algorithms simply not correct? I am mostly confused by the difference in aproximate odd/eveness of the results and the incontinuities regarding `a`.

```
octave> frft([1,0,0,0], 0.50)
   0.003910 - 0.548475i
   0.393301 - 0.072756i
  -0.349355 + 0.152855i
   0.051604 + 0.053868i

octave> frft2([1,0,0,0], 0.50)
  -0.0753 - 0.4989i
   0.2860 + 0.1183i
  -0.1111 + 0.1219i
   0.3095 - 0.1835i

octave> frft([1,0,0,0], 0.51)
  -0.012891 - 0.545906i
   0.390336 - 0.081043i
  -0.340700 + 0.175301i
   0.081861 + 0.048968i

octave> frft2([1,0,0,0], 0.51)
  -0.0962 - 0.4873i
   0.2876 + 0.1104i
  -0.0996 + 0.1328i
   0.3034 - 0.2179i

octave> frft([1,0,0,0], 0.49)
   0.3110 - 0.2646i
  -0.2468 + 0.2129i
   0.2468 - 0.2129i
  -0.3110 + 0.2646i

octave> frft2([1,0,0,0], 0.49)
   0.3207 - 0.0250i
  -0.2658 - 0.0597i
   0.2658 + 0.0597i
  -0.3207 + 0.0250i
```